# SQL Server 2005 time entry and time exit from eventime

Tags: sql-server-2005, time

I have two tables, `dbo.EMP` and `dbo.EVENTS`, with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EMP
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname NVARCHAR(64),
    lastname  NVARCHAR(64)
);

INSERT dbo.EMP SELECT 3370,'Ahmad','Gani';

CREATE TABLE dbo.EVENTS
(
    cardnum   INT, 
    eventime  SMALLDATETIME
);

INSERT dbo.Events
          SELECT 3370,'2011-08-01 07:55:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-01 09:50:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-01 13:30:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-01 16:35:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-02 07:45:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-02 10:55:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-02 12:07:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-02 15:07:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-02 16:30:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-03 08:07:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-03 12:07:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 3370,'2011-08-03 15:57:00';
```

Where do I start with a SQL Server 2005 query?

I want to get the results:

```
cardnum   lastname  time_entry              time_exit
3370      Gani      2011-08-01 07:55:00     2011-08-01 16:35:00
3370      Gani      2011-08-02 07:45:00     2011-08-02 16:30:00
3370      Gani      2011-08-03 08:07:00     2011-08-03 15:57:00
```

So that each row contains cardnum, lastname and two values from the eventime column. The first value from the eventie column should be the first entry for a specific date, and the second value should be the last entry for that specific date, where cardnum is the same.

Comment: How do you know the difference between time_entry, and time_exit?  Are you just assuming they'll always come in pairs?

Comment: Yes they always even more in one day. they are can be up 10 times. I want take first entry for time_entry and last entry for time_exit

Comment: They're not even in pairs, you seem to just take the first and last entry on each day and assume that the first one is a clock in and the last one is a clock out. That's what my answer solves but that doesn't seem realistic. Also, why do you need to store the first and last name of this user in the Events column? Surely you've normalized that into a users table, and can just look it up by cardnum? Also is your column really called eventime (one T) and not eventtime (two Ts)?

Comment: Oh sory mr. Aaron I am forget firtsname and lastname is in dbo.EMP table and cardnum, eventime in dbo.EVENT table. In my sample is result query from two table. In EMP table have coloum ID, firstname, lastname. and EVENTS table have coloum empid, cardnum, eventime. I want to query from two table for report time attendance

Comment: I've updated both the question (to provide DDL and sample data, as well as clarify that there are actually *two* tables involved) and updated my answer to reflect the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

New query given information added in comments:

```
;WITH x(cardnum, dt, time_entry, time_exit) AS 
(
  SELECT cardnum, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, eventime), 
    MIN(eventime), MAX(eventime)
  FROM dbo.EVENTS

  -- EDIT for more new requirements - for July 2011:

  WHERE eventime >= '20110701'
  AND eventime < '20110801'

  GROUP BY cardnum, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, eventime)
)
SELECT x.cardnum, e.lastname, x.time_entry, x.time_exit
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.EMP AS e
ON x.cardnum = e.ID;
```

Here is how @Andriy would suggest it:

```
SELECT ev.cardnum, e.lastname, MIN(ev.eventime), MAX(ev.eventime)
  FROM dbo.EVENTS AS ev
  INNER JOIN dbo.EMP AS e
  ON ev.cardnum = e.ID
  GROUP BY ev.cardnum, e.lastname, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ev.eventime);
```

However I find that less intuitive. While the plans are nearly identical with this small data size (slightly different location for the stream aggregate, but I'm not sure how much worse the sort operator will get at larger scale and I have no idea what indexes are on the table) and @Andriy's character count is obviously lower (317 characters vs. 204), his grouping is semantically mixed in with the joining, and I don't think all users will find it intuitive to see a `GROUP BY` column that isn't also in the `SELECT` list. These are mostly subjective reasons, of course.

Comment: Yes, and if you drop the DATEDIFF column and put the aliases for the aggregated columns beside them, you won't even need a CTE. :)

Comment: What's wrong with a CTE? Personally I find it helps both visually and logically separate the grouping from the display.

Comment: @Andriy updated my answer to illustrate your suggestion - with some caveats.

Comment: Sorry, I think I can see the confusion. I posted my comment when there was no join, which you added shortly afterwards. Anyway, I would accept your point even without the join. The idea of separating pure output from processing is not entirely new to me, as I sometimes end up with a statement with a series of CTEs where my main select pulls only columns from the last one. It's just that it would hardly ever occur to me to use the approach with a single CTE. But that is basically irrelevant after your adding the join. Thanks for taking your time to explain your point, really appreciated!

Comment: Thank's Mr. Aaron Bertrand. I just try for full one day and this night success query eventime from year 2008 to 2011, but I want to query per month ex. july 2011 where i put code condition.

Comment: Thank's very much for help me. If other time I want to help my problem, can you help me Mr?